# Generic type cast to class. Implement in Objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm trying to implement a simple observer/listener-pattern in `Objective-C`.

I have two `NSMutableArray` one with the different classes that are listening. These are cased to the generic type (`id`). I also have an array with the names (as `NSStrings`) for the different classes.

How can I take a generic type, cast back to the original class and send a message to that class?

I've tried something like this, but no success:

```
// _observers_type contains the names for the classes, _observers are the generic types.
- (void)notifyObservers;
{
    for (int i = 0; i < [_observers count]; i++) {
        NSString *classNameStr = [_observers_type objectAtIndex:i];
        Class theClass = NSClassFromString(classNameStr);
        (theClass)[[_observers objectAtIndex:i] triggerNotify];
    }
}
```

Also note, these methods are not instance-methods. I want to update views etc with this pattern.

Comment: Sorry, please restate.  Are you saying they're "class" methods (`+` prefix)?

Comment: And why do you need two separate arrays? A single array with all observers should be sufficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code

```
for (int i = 0; i < [_observers count]; i++) {
    [[_observers objectAtIndex:i] performSelector:@selector(triggerNotify)];
}
```

theClass is evaluated in run-time so for compiler this line

```
(theClass)[[_observers objectAtIndex:i] triggerNotify];
```

has the same information as this

```
[[_observers objectAtIndex:i] triggerNotify];
```

and it will generate an error "no known instance method for selector 'triggerNotify'".

Calling this

```
[[_observers objectAtIndex:i] performSelector:@selector(triggerNotify)];
```

sends to the receiver the same message but without asking compiler is it possible or not.

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thanks a lot. I'll accept in 9 minutes. Could you explain why this works and simply sending the message does not?

Comment: Every object from _observers  will receive triggerNotify message. As I understand this is exactly what @OptimusCrime wants.

Comment: There is no difference between this and `[[_observers objectAtIndex:i] triggerNotify]`.

Comment: I think `performSelector:` was necessary because the OP isn't importing headers for any classes that implement the `triggerNotify` method in the class where he's calling this method. Either that or he didn't add the method to any of his header files. This is mentioned in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to cast — and in fact in this case you *can't* cast, because you have a class object, not a type, so there's nothing to cast to.

Instead, just send the message.

If you're getting a compile-time error from the message send, that means you haven't imported any headers that declare the method. Just import a header for a class or protocol that has the method.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up. I see that now. Casting back to the original class makes no sense.

Answer (score 1):

You can send a message to an object declared as id.

```
for (id object in observers)
    [object triggerNotify];
```

You can only use casts to types that are known at compile time, so what you are doing isn't going to work and cannot work. But you can send any message to an id - just make sure that the id actually responds to the message. So it would be safe to write

```
for (id object in observers)
    if ([object respondsToSelector:@selector (triggerNotify)])
        [object triggerNotify];
```

It's quite pointless to store the names of the classes, because you can just use [object class] if you want to know the class.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your code, all of your classes respond to the selector `triggerNotify`, so you should just be able to call that on all of the objects without issue:

```
[[_observers objectAtIndex:i] triggerNotify];
```

There should be no need to typecast this. As long as the method `triggerNotify` exists somewhere in some class, the compiler shouldn't complain that you're calling it.

EDIT:

Based on your comments on my answer, you're most likely not importing headers from any classes that implement this method in the class where this code is. So it should work if you simply import the header for a class that implements this. Otherwise, you can use the suggestion from another answer that says to use `performSelector:`, which will allow it to compile even if the selector doesn't exist anywhere.

To be as safe as possible, however, you should check to see if the objects respond to the selector first before calling `performSelector:`:

```
if ([[_observers objectAtIndex:i] respondsToSelector:@selector(triggerNotify)])
```

Comment: This gave me error saying "No known instance method for selector 'triggerNotify'". It was the first thing I tried.

Comment: Then `triggerNotify` must not be an instance method for any classes in your project. Are you sure that the objects in your array respond to that?

Comment: @OptimusCrime: That means the object in the array does not respond to `triggerNotify`. The object has to implement the method.

Comment: It is an instance method for one of my classes.

Comment: @OptimusCrime Is it a compile time error or a runtime error? Does it happen when you try to build it or when the program is running?

Comment: @OptimusCrime I added to my answer details about why it was probably necessary to use `performSelector:`, and also how to make this safer in case your array happens to contain an object that doesn't respond to that selector.

Comment: Ah. I see now. I get the error while trying to compile in xcode. I did not add the headers for the other classes. `respondToSelector` worked without having to add them.